# Why static class cannot be instantiated

Tags: c#, .net, class, static

Well i know the static class are allocated in "High Frequency Heap" and they are built for the speedy access purposes and all but the thing this what is happening inside ? Why they are not allowed to instantiate.

Actually was interested to know what happens internally when the compiler sees the word "Static"

Comment: Static classes are "static" they will not rely on instance variables and have no own state.

Comment: This reminds me the question `why sealed classes can't be inherited` ...

Comment: The question makes no sense. The `static` keyword was invented to create a class that cannot and does not need to be instantiated. So asking why it is so is a circular reference.

Comment: A static class is defined as a class that cannot be instantiated. Therefore, they can't be instantiated.

Comment: By marking a class as `static`, you are explicitly saying that there are no instances of the class, only behaviors attached to the type. That's what it _means_.

Comment: @JohnWillemse this is not circular reference. It's like saying `Why did the ball fall when you drop it` is circular reference

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Why is the class static? Because you cannot instantiate it. Why can't I instantiate it? Because it is static. Why is the class static? Because you cannot instantiate it. Why can't I instantiate it? Because ..., etc. ;-)

Comment: Down voters please find the edit

Comment: @JohnWillemse That's circular reasoning. The question `why static class is non-instantiable` is non-circular, because there is a valid answer - because compiler team intended the `static` clause in class definition to forbid instantiation. Now if you want to ask `why did they want to do this` that's whole another question (not circular).

Comment: @IlyaIvanov exactly was asking same question as to how static will be seen by compiler when it is with class in the mean time every one started down voting :(

Comment: @Shrivallabh just for the future - try to devote more time to questions you ask. The point you where searching was much deeper, than you stated in the question. Always do your homework before asking something and you will receive the best answer SO can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> A static class is basically the same as a non-static class, but there
>   is one difference: a static class cannot be instantiated. In other
>   words, you cannot use the new keyword to create a variable of the
>   class type. **Because there is no instance variable**, you access the
>   members of a static class by using the class name itself.

Comment: @Shrivallabh, thats a different question, `static` keyword would have different meaning with class, methods, properties etc.

Comment: Ya wanted to know the same thing with class and every one down voted :(

Comment: @Shrivallabh, how it is implemented and interpreted by compiler is the implementation details, probably known to Microsoft employees. This [link (static class msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has enough information about its working

Comment: Thank you Sir Got it at the basic level

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to create instances of a static class.

> Static classes and class members are used to create data and functions that can be accessed without creating an instance of the class. Static class members can be used to separate data and behavior that is independent of any object identity: the data and functions do not change regardless of what happens to the object. Static classes can be used when there is no data or behavior in the class that depends on object identity.

The main features of a static class are:

- They only contain static members.
- They cannot be instantiated.
- They are sealed.
- They cannot contain Instance Constructors (C# Programming Guide).
- List item

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx